# Virtual Tables in Power BI based on Slicer

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I am trying to create a virtual table that is based on the selected value in a date slicer.  I can't quite figure this out in Power BI.  In theory, this is what I'm trying to do in SQL terms:  The @Datekey and the @CompareDate being two different slicers in the report.

```
Select * from (
    Select
        storeid
        ,rollratebucket
        ,bucketkey
        ,principalbalance
        ,LoanCount
        ,datekey
        ,activestatus
    from reporting.bi_rollrates1) a
left join (
Select
        storeid
        ,rollratebucket
        ,bucketkey
        ,principalbalance
        ,LoanCount
        ,datekey
        ,activestatus
from reporting.bi_rollrates1) b

on a.bucketkey = b.bucketkey - 1
and a.storeid = b.storeid
and a.activestatus = b.activestatus

where a.datekey = @DateKey
and b.datekey = @CompareDate
```

```
FilteredData = 
VAR SelectedDateValue = [SelectedDate]
VAR PreviousDateValue = [PreviousDate]
RETURN
CALCULATETABLE(
    SUMMARIZE(
        query1,
        Query1[TerritoryID],
        Query1[AreaID],
        Query1[RegionID],
        Query1[DistrictID],
        query1[storeid],
        query1[rollratebucket],
        query1[bucketkey],
        query1[principalbalance],
        query1[LoanCount],
        query1[datekey],
        query1[activestatus]
    ),
    query1[datekey] = SelectedDateValue || query1[datekey] = PreviousDateValue,
    ALL(query1)  // This removes any existing filters on the query1 table
)
```